# Helm how to copy section of complex values.yaml into a configmap

Tags: nested, yaml, kubernetes-helm, go-templates, configmap

I have a large values.yaml file that consists of nested objects, arrays that I am trying to render a copy of as a configmap. My code so far is:

```
{{- range $key, $value := index .Values "program_config" }}
{{ $key }}
{{- range $elem, $elemVal := $value }}
{{- if kindIs "invalid" $elemVal }}
{{ $elem }} = 
{{- else if kindIs "string" $elemVal }}
{{ $elem }} = {{ tpl $elemVal $ }}
{{- else }}
{{ $elem }} = {{ $elemVal }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

this gets me fairly close, but I am seeing issues with maps rendering as

```
object_schema : map[type:UTF8]
```

instead of

```
object_schema:
  type: "UTF8"
```

and my arrays are showing up as:

```
queries :
0 : select xxx
```

instead of:

```
queries:
 - >-
   select xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

After several hours worked thru it, this did it for me:

```
{{- range $key, $value := index .Values "program_config" }}
    {{ $key }}:
    {{- range $elem, $elemVal := $value }}
      {{- if ne "queries" $key  }}
      {{- if ne "schema" $key  }}
      {{- if kindIs "invalid" $elemVal }}
      {{ $elem }}: {{ "" }}
      {{- else if kindIs "string" $elemVal }}
      {{ $elem }}: {{ tpl $elemVal $ | quote}}
      {{- else }}
      {{ $elem }}: {{ quote $elemVal }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- if eq "queries" $key  }}
      - >-
        {{ $elemVal }}
      {{- end}}
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- range $key, $value := index .Values.program_config.schema}}
      {{ $key }}: 
      {{- range $nestedKey, $nestedVal := index $value }}
        {{ $nestedKey }} : {{ $nestedVal | quote }}
      {{- end }}   
{{- end }}
```